# selenium, с# Как открыть панель разработчика в отдельном окне?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

для открытия панели разработчика использую вот это

```
--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

можно ли открыть панель разработчика в отдельном окне?(пользуюсь c#)

Comment: такой возможности нет

Comment: а если нажать кнопки Ctrl, Shift, i?

Comment: попробуйте, не поможет, максимум чего вы добьетесь это смены позиции Right -> Bottom и обратно)